# plotting and shading curves generates unwanted lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a normal distribution and shade under the curve in R but I am getting a unwanted problems below the curve.

```
x <- seq(-3,3,0.0001)   
y <- dnorm(x,0,1)
ytop <- dnorm(-3,3,0.001)
df <-data.frame(x=x,y=y)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() 

cover <- rbind(c(1,0), subset(df, x > 1), c(df[nrow(df), "X"], 0))

 p + geom_segment(aes(x=1,y=0, xend=2.5, yend=ytop)) +
     geom_polygon(data = cover, aes(x, y))
```

Can someone explain to me why I am messing up this figure and getting the lines underneath the shaded area?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you didn't go to y=0 at the extremes of your polygon definition.

Comment: hmm though `tail(cover)` shows the last values for `y` are `0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made two errors that I see: 1) using "X" when the column name is "x" and failing to complete the polygon back to (x=1,y=0) at the end.

```
   cover <- do.call(rbind, list( data.frame(x=1,y=0), 
                                 subset(df, x > 1),  # the x,y points
                                  data.frame(x=df[nrow(df), "x"],y= 0), # drop to y=0
                                  data.frame(x=1,y=0)) )  # complete the bottom
  p + geom_segment(aes(x=1,y=0, xend=2.5, yend=ytop)) +
       geom_polygon(data = cover, aes(x, y))
```

On my machine I also notice that the graphics engine seemed to leave a one pixel jump along the bottom which I could remove with a rather hackish ad-hoc adjustment:

```
 cover <- do.call(rbind, list( data.frame(x=1,y=0), 
                               subset(df, x > 1), 
                               data.frame(x=df[nrow(df), "x"],y= -0.001), 
                               data.frame(x=1,y=0)) )
```

(I think I'm just compensating for someone else's error but maybe the Earth is curved out at SD > 2?)

And a bit more experimentation suggest the ad-hoc adjustment along with correcting the "X" spelling would besufficient (that geom_polygon is smart enough to close itself):

```
cover <- do.call(rbind, list( data.frame(x=1,y=0), 
                              subset(df, x > 1), 
                              data.frame(x=df[nrow(df), "x"],y= -0.001)) )
```

Comment: thanks for showing me where i was going wrong, finishing back at `x=1` and `y=0` ! and super plus on for clearing up that extra pixel I just noticed after seeing your initial answer!

Comment: .@Dwin if I may ask your advice, i am currently trying to change the colour of the polygon as a funciton of the `x` e.g. `covert$col    <- 1:nrow(cover)` but `fill` will only set one colour per polygon. I was wondering if you knew this was possible or not and maybe worthy of a question if I cant figure it out?

Comment: hmm looks like I would need tomake many polygons across x to get a fill gradient, maybe ggplot is not the way and there is another approach to get fill gradient under the curve.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler way to do this.

```
x <- seq(-3,3,0.0001)   
y <- dnorm(x,0,1)
df <-data.frame(x=x,y=y)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(df,x>1), aes(ymin=0, ymax=y))
```

[image]